# IE 8 speed/performance issues when rendering large image

Tags: image, internet-explorer, performance, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers with a large image (7000x5500) as a map representation. On FF and Chrome, I'm able to drag/drop/zoom the image normally. However, when I open it on IE 8, just rendering the image (shown in a 300 x 300 div) causes major speed issues. The site gets awfully slow. Maybe it has something to do with rescaling the image, but it works fine in other browsers. There is only one request for the image being triggered, so multiple requests don't seem to be the cause. Any tips on how to improve IE 8 performance when handling such large images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone is wondering, we solved this by pre-processing the image and decreasing its resolution in a http handler. No way IE8 could handle a 7000x5500 image properly.

Comment: rla4.. I am facing the same problem. Can you explain a bit more on how you managed to decrease the resolution in the http handler?

Comment: Shaunak, in case you're still wondering.. I'm sorry it took me so long to get back to you. https://gist.github.com/1705728